# Can Arduino Portenta H7 board connect with windows via bluetooth?

Tags: arduino

This is a straight forward question, does the portenta h7 have support to connect to my windows through BLE.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer Yes; long answer, the Arduino Portenta H7 has a built-in BT module that supports BLE. So you can use the ArduinoBLE library to create a BLE central device on the Portenta H7, and connect it to Windows acting as a BLE device.

If the ArduinoBLE not work, then reset the Portenta and try the Bluefruit52 library, test with a simple code like this: (after pair, remember to open the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE and set the baud rate to 115200)

```js
 #include <bluefruit.h>

// Define the service and characteristic UUIDs
BLEService helloService("19B10000-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214");
BLECharacteristic helloCharacteristic("19B10001-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLEWrite | BLENotify, 20);

void setup() {
  // Initialize the Bluefruit52 module
  Bluefruit.begin();
  Bluefruit.setName("Portenta H7");
  Bluefruit.Periph.setConnectionInterval(80, 80);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addFlags(BLE_GAP_ADV_FLAGS_LE_ONLY_GENERAL_DISC_MODE);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addTxPower();

  // Set up the advertising data
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addService(helloService);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addData(helloCharacteristic);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.restartOnDisconnect(true);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.setInterval(32, 244);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.setFastTimeout(30);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.start(0);

  // Set up the characteristic callback
  helloCharacteristic.setEventHandler(BLECharacteristic::BLEWritten, [](BLECharacteristic *characteristic) {
    uint8_t buffer[20];
    uint16_t len = characteristic->read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    Serial.write(buffer, len);
  });

  // Start the serial communication
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);
}

void loop() {
  // Check for a Bluetooth connection
  if (Bluefruit.connected()) {
    // Read the serial data and send it to the connected computer
    while (Serial.available()) {
      helloCharacteristic.write(Serial.read());
    }

    // Read the Bluetooth data and send it to the serial port
    uint8_t buffer[20];
    uint16_t len = helloCharacteristic.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (len > 0) {
      Serial.write(buffer, len);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on this, I have tried multiple codes but on the library you have mentioned, but all seem to have the same result, that is, whenever i try to pair my portenta to windows, it disconnects.

Comment: The code you provided has the library `#include<bluefruit.h>` has no compatibility with portenta h7.

Answer (score 0):

BLE does work, but this might just not be what you are looking for. You cannot have your Serial Monitor via Bluetooth or to do OTA uploads via BLE. In theory the Portenta is capable of bluetooth classic but there is no firmware or lib to use it just now. Which I must say was very disapointing to hear form the support because they advertised it as such.